# How to revert a transformation?

Tags: math, transformation

I have a following transformation when doing some kind of zoom/upscaling of a point. My goal is to calculate an offset based on this scale.

My problem is that when going from a big scale to a smaller scale I'd of course have the offset to be the same. Eg if I scale from 3 to 4 and back from 4 to 3, the offset on scale of 3 should always be the same.

But with my formula, it is not. And I cannot get my head around what I'm doing wrong:

```
px = 200
offset = 0
scale: 1, and goes always +-1
```

calculation based on forumla: `newOffset = oldOffset +- px / scale;`

```
scale = 2 => offset = 0      + 200 / 2 = 100
scale = 3 => offset = 100    + 200 / 3 = 166,67
scale = 4 => offset = 166,67 + 200 / 4 = 216,67
```

How can I revert the scaling?

```
scale = 3 => offset = 216,67 - 200 / 3 = 150 # //it should evaluate to 166,67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offsets are defined by a recursion relation:

```
offset(0) = 0
offset(i) = offset(i-1) + px/(i+1)
```

Or, if we were to write out the first few terms,

```
offset0 = 0
offset1 = offset0 + px/2 = 100
offset2 = offset1 + px/3 = offset0 + px/2 + px/3 = 166.67
offset3 = offset2 + px/4 = offset0 + px/2 + px/3 + px/4 = 216.67
```

So the offsets are equal to a constant, `offset0`, plus the first N terms of the harmonic series (the sum of terms `1/n` for n = 2,3,...) scaled by `px`.

There is no closed form algebraic expression for the first N terms of the harmonic series, so either store the numbers and look them up as needed, or recompute the value when you "rescale".